# Problema para login password verify

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este codigo, se supone que está bien ya lo revise muchas veces y esta bien hecho. Pero, el password_verify no funciona, he visto que puede ser por el campo de la base de datos MySQL. Es de tipo varchar (255) y utf8mb4_unicode_ci  por si ayuda. ¿Me podrían ayudar con este problema?

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

try {
    $sql = "SELECT email, password from users where email= :email";
    if($inicio = $base_de_datos->prepare($sql)){
        $inicio->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $inicio->execute(); 
        $mData=$inicio->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $outPut = array(
            'status'=>password_verify($password,$mData['password']),
            'msg'=>'Ok'
        );
    }
    else {
        $outPut=array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>'Error prepare');
    }
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $outPut=array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>$ex->getMessage());
    return $outPut;
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    header("location: gestion.php?error");
}
var_dump($outPut);
```

Comment: Devuelve algún error? Seria de utilidad conocer mas datos.

Comment: Dos dudas me asaltan: 1. ¿Está todo bien en el `$_POST`? ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);` en ese contexto? Pregunto porque programas de forma ingenua en ese sentido, buscando datos en el `$_POST` sin verificar nada. ¿Qué pasa si no se postean esos datos o si vienen bajo otras claves? 2. ¿Hiciste un `password_hash()` cuando insertaste la contraseña? Dado que soy como santo Tomás, muéstranos el código de inserción que usaste al momento de guardar la contraseña. Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta. Por otra parte, creo que bastaría con hacer un solo `catch` de `Exception` y punto.